# ArrayToString problema en if instanceOf

Tags: java, array, string, bucles

Queria saber porque no me imprime por pantalla, los valores, y sin embargo realizandolo de forma simple sin iteradores, si me esta funcionando.
De forma simple funciona

```
Avion a = (Avion) lista.get(0);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.getAzafatas()));
```

Y con el iterador me esta fallando..

```
if (lista.get(i) instanceof Avion) {
                                Avion x = (Avion) lista.get(i);
                                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x.getAzafatas()));

                            }
```

Y aqui esta el metodo, aunque no creo que este aqui el fallo..

```
public String [] getAzafatas (){
        return azafatas;
    }
```

Este es mi arrayList

```
 ArrayList<Vehiculo> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(new Avion(new String[]{"Juana", "Lola"}, "Delta"));
        lista.add(new Avion(new String[]{"Pepa", "Maria"}, "Caza"));
        lista.add(new Avion(new String[]{"Adela", "Risberta"}, "Rocket"));
        lista.add(new Bicicleta("Orbea", "Roja"));
        lista.add(new Bicicleta("Rail", "Verde"));
        lista.add(new Bicicleta("Spinn", "Amarillo"));
        lista.add(new Bicicleta("BH", "Rosa"));
        lista.add(new Coche(50, "Porsche"));
        lista.add(new Coche(20, "Seat"));
        lista.add(new Coche(30, "Fiat"));
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que te está fallando? ¿Hay algún error? Agrégalo a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Gracias Cedano, siempre estas atento a mis preguntas, soy novato, y se agradece muchisimo. Me refiero con error, a que no imprime los valores que hay dentro del String array.

Comment: ¿Qué imprine si no? ¿Qué hay en `lista.get(i);`? Además, si es una instancia de `Avion` no necesitas hacer esto: `Avion x = (Avion) lista.get(i);` sino usar `lista.get(i);` el cual, según el `if` será una instancia de `Avion`

Comment: O sea, bastaría con hacer esto: **`if (lista.get(i) instanceof Avion) { System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lista.get(i).getAzafatas())); }`** Pero si ni siquiera nos dices qué hay en `lista.get(i)` o qué imprime tu código exactamente, no podremos ayudarte de la mejor manera.

Comment: Utilizo Avion x = (Avion) lista.get(i); Debido a que he creado un ArrayList de tipo Objeto Vehiculo, en el que he añadido objetos de otras clases, como Avion, es la unica forma que conozco de poder acceder a un metodo reservado, de la clase Avion que es getAzafatas

Comment: Este es mi array ArrayList<Vehiculo> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        lista.add(new Avion(new String[]{"Juana", "Lola"}, "Delta"));
        lista.add(new Avion(new String[]{"Pepa", "Maria"}, "Caza"));
        lista.add(new Avion(new String[]{"Adela", "Risberta"}, "Rocket"));

Comment: Pero, si vas a meter objetos de la clase `Avion` en la lista, debes declarla así: `ArrayList<Avion> lista = new ArrayList<>();` Si el problema sigue, pon la clase `Avion` completa para revisarla. Así como el contexto completo donde intentas leer lista, pues no se ve de dónde sacas `i `  ¿?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124777/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-alvaro-g).